# Select n rows around every specific row meeting condition

Tags: r

I have a `DF`

```
A   B    C
NA  0.1  100
NA  0.2  200
1   0.3  300
NA  0.4  400
NA  0.5  500
1   0.5  600
NA  0.6  700
NA  0.6  800
```

I need to select all rows if `DF$A=1`. Additionally, I need to select all rows below and above `DF$A=1` rows so that  `DF$C-100` & `DF$C+100`
So that the output will be

```
     A   B    C
    NA  0.2  200
    1   0.3  300
    NA  0.4  400
    NA  0.5  500
    1   0.5  600
    NA  0.6  700
```

I would expect it should be something like this

```
if (DF$A==1) print(c(DF[DF$C-100 & DF$C+100, ]))
```

But of course it doesnt work..
Thank you for any clues.

Comment: Why did you exclude `NA  0.5  500` from your expected results?

Comment: (b) Is it the row order order that matters or do you want all matches based on `C` value? Or do you assume that the data is already sorted by `C`?

Comment: Sorry, just my mistake.

Comment: (c) Your example only looks at one row above and below, is it possible that there are more matches? If so, is it possible that matches will overlap? If they overlap should they only be included a single time?

Comment: There is no order, and i dont expect it to be ordered.

Comment: Yes in my real data there could be overlap actually, and should be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first finding the indices for `which` `df$A==1`, and then concatenating all indices `+/- 1` from that:

```
ind <- which(df$A==1)
out <- df[sort(unique(c(ind-1,ind,ind+1))),]
##   A   B   C
##2 NA 0.2 200
##3  1 0.3 300
##4 NA 0.4 400
##5 NA 0.5 500
##6  1 0.5 600
##7 NA 0.6 700
```

Here, we find all the `unique` indices from the concatenated indices, and we `sort` them for the subset. If you really don't care about the order, you don't need to sort, but the `unique` is necessary for handling the overlap.

Comment: Thank you! That just i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this. Calling your data `dd`:

```
# select matching C values
matches = dd[!is.na(dd$A), "C", drop = F]
names(matches) = "C_test"  # rename to avoid confusion
result = merge(matches, dd, by = NULL)  # cross join
# filter out bad matches, deduplicate
result = unique(with(result, result[abs(C - C_test) <= 100, ])[-1])

    A   B   C
3  NA 0.2 200
5   1 0.3 300
7  NA 0.4 400
10 NA 0.5 500
12  1 0.5 600
14 NA 0.6 700
```

As (I think) you indicated in the comments, this will ignore the row order of the original data and focus only on the `C` value comparisons.